# How to make a function that navigate when user input equal to the If Condition Using angular

Tags: html, angular, router

I want to make a function that checks the user input if is equal to (username:"marwen" , password:"hamdi") then navigate to the URL `'apps/e-commerce/products'`

**This is the TypeScript:**

```
ngOnInit(): void{
    this.loginForm = this._formBuilder.group({
        email   : ["", [Validators.required] ],
        password: ["", Validators.required]
    });           
}

check(){
    if (this.email.value==="marwen"&& this.password.value==="hamdi"){
        this.router.navigate(['apps/e-commerce/products'])
    } 
}
```

And this is the HTML part where I want to execute the function when I click on the button.

```
<form name="loginForm" [formGroup]="loginForm" novalidate >
    <mat-form-field appearance="outline" style="color:white;">
        <mat-label style="color:white;">Nom d'Utilisateur</mat-label>
        <input matInput formControlName="email" id="email">
        <mat-icon matSuffix class="secondary-text" style="color:white;">
            supervised_user_circle
        </mat-icon>
        <mat-error *ngIf="loginForm.get('email').hasError('required')">         
            Nom d'utilisateur est requis
        </mat-error> 
    </mat-form-field>
    <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
        <mat-label style="color:white;">Mot De Passe</mat-label>
        <input matInput type="password" formControlName="password" id="password">
        <mat-icon matSuffix class="secondary-text" style="color:white;" >vpn_key</mat-icon>
        <mat-error>
            Mot De Passe est requis
        </mat-error>
    </mat-form-field>
    <button  mat-raised-button color="accent" class="submit-button" aria-label="LOG IN" [disabled]="loginForm.invalid" (click)="check()" >
        Connexion        
    </button>
</form>
```

Comment: `client-side` validation like this is easily bypassed - you should not rely upon it for any means of security

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope you are using this validation only as test or mock your login. Anyways, this can help you:

```
ngOnInit() {
    // do something with this subscription
    this.loginForm.valueChanges.subscribe(values => {
      if (values.email === "marwen" && values.value==="hamdi") {
        this.router.navigate(['apps/e-commerce/products'])
      }
    });
}
```

Comment: should i do it in the ngOnInit??

Comment: yes you should, even better if you do a function like listenFormChanges(){.. code in the answer}